# Программное определение кодировки текстового файла из заданного списка

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм, кодировка

Задача нетривиальная: написать программу на `C/C++` ("чистом"), на вход которой подается путь к файлу, на выходе - кодировка этого файла с указанием точности: точно или наиболее вероятно. (содержит буквы английского и/или русского языков, и пр. символы; в файле может быть исходник программы на одном из языков программирования).

Список требуемых к распознаванию кодировок: `simple ASCII, CP1251 (windows 1251), ISO8859-5, CP866, KOI8-R, UTF8, UTF16-LE, UTF16-BE, UTF32-LE, UTF32-BE, UCS-2`. Ошибки: кодировка `undefined` или файл бинарный (`unreadable`).

Задача на эвристический анализ, понятно, что однозначного решения нет.
Здесь хотелось бы собрать воедино все признаки отличия этих кодировок друг от друга, а также конфликтование этих признаков между собой, чтобы составить алгоритм.

Существуют `BOM` (`Byte Order Mark`) для `UTF8` (может не быть), для `UTF16LE(BE)`, `UTF32LE(BE)`, по которым их легко можно определить, но в таком случае возникает тонкая грань между `UCS-2` и `UTF-16` - возникает проблема в их различении...

Имеются неполные решения задачи: команда `file -i [path]` для `UNIX` (есть порт для `WIN`), которая по специальной таблице встречаемости кодов символов в разных кодировках умеет определять `ASCII`, `ISO8859-5` (которую путает с `Win-1251`), `UTF8, UTF16, EBCDIC`, но 8-битные `non-ISO` кодировки именует `8-bit unknown`.

По каким признакам можно отличить `KOI8-R, WIN-1251, ISO8859-5, CP866, ASCII` (т.е. все однобайтовые в данном случае)?
`UCS-2 = UTF16` без "суррогатных пар".

Существует также утилита `ENCA` для `UNIX`, которая умеет определять кодировки в более широком диапазоне, но принцип работы ее непонятен.

Заранее благодарю за любую помощь.

Comment: Существуют вроде еще методы определения кодировки по разделителям строк, абзацев и пр.
CR, LF, CR+LF - только должного описания, какой разделитель присущ какой кодировке найти не удалось.

Comment: >  - [https://github.com/dcramer/chardet/tree/master/chardet][1]

>  - [http://enca.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1.12-1/files.html][2]


  [1]: https://github.com/dcramer/chardet/tree/master/chardet
  [2]: http://enca.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1.12-1/files.html

Comment: @Kalash По разделителям строк кодировку не определить, разве что только вероятную платформу `(win / unix / mac)`, на которой создан данный файл.

Comment: Я делал такую программу (just for fun), но 

1) для **русского** языка

2) только для **однобайтных кодировок** (включая UTF-8)

--

"Угадывание" проводится на основе статистики частоты символов в русском тексте. Просто взял несколько книжек и набрал статистику русских букв.

Т.е. предполагая, что файл в данной кодировке, считаем частоты букв и сравниваем с "эталоном". Для какой кодировки отклонение меньше, ту и считаем правильной. 

Понятно, что если файл **не в UTF-8**, то это быстро отлавливается.

Ясно, что такой подход работает в основном для *"осмысленных"* текстов.

Comment: Хотел бы увидеть сей проект в виде git или на googlecode :-)

Comment: @gecube, до приличного вида я этот "проект" не довел - работа появилась (доки нет, да и ошибок, наверное полно). 

Если Вам интересно, то могу src.zip (~0.5M но там намного больше лишнего, чем относящегося к кодировкам) куда-нибудь кинуть.

Comment: @gecube, скайпа и аськи у меня нет. Положил на http://zalil.ru/33578199

Comment: > но принцип работы ее непонятен.

насколько я понял, использование вероятностных матриц. Причем не только для самих символов, но и для их пар.

Comment: Вспомните алгоритм пунто свитчера, определение раскладки по наличию редко встречающихся комбинаций букв в русском языке.

Comment: @avp, если я правильно помню, то частотные словари есть готовые, также можно раздобыть корпус языка. Ещё одна проблема — двойные кодировки (KOI8-R поверх CP1251, например).

Comment: @0andriy, а в чем проблема с двойными кодировками? Вы просто определите, что это русский язык в неизвестной программе однобайтной кодировке.

Answer (score 3):

Когда-то давно, мне попалась картинка (см. ниже)

Подходов могу предложить два:

1) Мы пишем парсер, исходя из каждой кодировки (думаю, ориентироваться будем в первую очередь на кирилицу). Если на вход, подается что-то, чего не может быть в кодировке (спецсимволы и т.п. - мы отбрасываем эту кодировку и идем дальше).

2)

1. Проверяем заголовок файла, а вдруг нам повезет и там будет метка мультибайтовой кодировки.
2. Вычищаем файл (убираем пробелы, знаки пунктуации).
3. Убираем латинские буквы и цифры.
4. Убираем нормальные спецсимволы {}[]<>$% и т.п.
   Если ничего не остается, говорим, что хрен его знает в какой он кодировке - спецзнаков нету.
5. Подсчитываем оставщиеся знаки. Отдельно считаем как однобайтовые так и мульти (перемножаем на лету). Я бы юзал коллекции.
6. Определяем (роясь в инете, или анализирую самодельные текст) рамки кодировок.
   Правильность берем, как отношение числа ошибок (символов, которые не могут быть кирилическими в данной кодировке) к числу правильных знаков. Правильным считаем ту кодировку, в которой удалось вложиться в рамки без ошибок. Если таких нет - выводим по убыванию ошибок.

Само собой, чем больше текст, тем ниже вероятность ошибки. По наблюдениям, после 500 знаков (кроме случаев повторения одинакового) ошибки исключены.

[image: Алгоритм кодировок]

Answer (score 1):

Что касается `UTF8`, `UCS2` и `ANSI`, их легко различить. Вернее сказать - если нет повторений через байт, то это уже 99.9% не юникод(`UCS2: Big/Little Endian`).

Далее если есть байты выше `0x7F`, то нужно смотреть на последовательность байтов. количество старших битов показывают количество байтов символа в `UTF`. к примеру **`110x xxxx`** этот байт говорит что за нм есть еще байт который, если это `UTF8` будет больше или равен `0x80`(`10xx xxxx`) и меньше чем `0xC0`(`1100 0000`), или например байт с маской **`1110 xxxx`** говорит о том что за ним два байта с маской **`10xx xxxx`**, байты меньше `0x80` обозначают обычные символы `ANSI`. по сути из-за данного вида кодирования `UTF8` даже и в маркере не нуждается.

Что касается `UCS-2`, то здесь просто смотрим на различия между байтами. Берем из текста по 2 байта, если по одному из них разница не более 3 а средняя длина цепочки составляет больше 2-х, то уже на 50% можно сказать что юникод.

Я делал 3 теста: тест на разные байты(количество), средняя длина слова, ну и третий, особо не нужный количество последовательностей одинаковых байтов выше 3-х и выше 6-ти символов из общего количества последовательностей. В принципе дает очень неплохой результат.