# Кто может помочь с Парсером?

Tags: парсер

```html
<?php
require_once 'curl/curl.php';
require_once 'phpquery/phpQuery/phpQuery.php';

$curl = new Curl();
$response = $curl->get( 'урл сайта');

$doc= phpQuery::newDocument($response->body);

$product=$doc->find('.product');
echo "<table>";
foreach ($product as $product){

  $pq= pq($product);
  echo "<tr><td>". $pq->find('.jshop_code_prod span')->text() .'</td>' ;
        echo "<td>". $pq->find('.name h3 a ')->text() .'</td> ';
  echo "<td>". $pq->find('.jshop_price span')->text() .'</td> ';
  echo "</tr>";

  }
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Цена и артикул норм выводит, но вот имя - 
Выдает такие символы - ÐÐ¾ÑÐ¾Ð±ÐºÐ° Ð´Ð»Ñ Ð½Ð°ÑÑÐ¶Ð½Ð¾Ð³Ð¾ Ð¼Ð¾Ð½ÑÐ°Ð¶Ð° ASFORA Ð±ÐµÐ»Ð°Ñ (Ð¨Ð½Ð°Ð¹Ð´ÐµÑ
Тестил на разных сайтах - на некоторых корректно отображает русский шрифт на некоторых символы выше!
В чем может быть причина?

Comment: очевидно в кодировке.

Comment: [Определить кодировку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/321887/186999) или даже лучше вот [Программное определение кодировки текстового файла из заданного списка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/126210/186999)